# Setting up a system variable for Java

Tags: java, system, environment

Just started programming in Java, and I found some guides detailing how to set up a Path variable. One said to make a ёJAVA_HOMEё variable and reference it in the `PATH` variable like this: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` and the other says to put the directory (with bin) in the `PATH` variable directly. Is there any difference (access rights)?

Comment: difference in relative and absolute path of `bin` directory.

Answer (score 0):

1. In first case, you can change JAVA_HOME, and Path will be looking at the latest Java.
2. In second case, you'll have to change it in 2 places in JAVA_HOME and in PATH, otherwise you'll have surprisses in behavior.

So I go with the first one.
This is preferable general approach,

Comment: Is JAVA_HOME necessary for something other than  using it in the Path variable?

Comment: This system property is used by many programs, that depend on java, so you'll need it anyway in your classpath.